# NoReverseMatch at /alumni/2/alumni_cv/ Reverse for 'alumni_profile' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: django

I am facing problem.

code in template alumni_cv.html:

```
<a href="{% url 'alumni_cv' user.alumniprofile.id %}"
class="btn
btn-primary btn-block"><b>CV</b></a>
```

When I click this button, the following error appears:

```
NoReverseMatch at /alumni/2/alumni_cv/
Reverse for 'alumni_profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) 
tried: ['alumni/alumni_profile/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']
```

models.py code:

```
class AlumniProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='alumni/', null=True, blank=True, default="default_user_avatar.jpg")
    bio = models.TextField()
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    district_of_birth = models.ForeignKey(
        TownCityDistrict, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=genders)
    present_address = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    permanent_address = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    blood_group = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=blood_groups)
    university_bachelor_session = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    university_masters_session = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    university_hall = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    university_batch = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    facebook_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    linkedin_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    instagram_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    twitter_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    skype_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    zoom_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.phone)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Alumni'


class AlumniEducation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AlumniProfile, null=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exam = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, verbose_name='Examination/Degree', blank=True, null=True)
    exam_year = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Examination Year', blank=True, null=True)
    institute = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, verbose_name='Institute Name', blank=True, null=True)
    board_university = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, verbose_name='Board/University', blank=True, null=True)
    result = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Result/Grade', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.exam

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Education Profile'


class AlumniJobExperience(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AlumniProfile, null=True, blank=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    job_location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_join = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    now_on_job = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_resignation = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    responsibilities = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    achievements = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Job Experience'


class AlumniProfessionalSkill(models.Model):
    professional_skill = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    professional_skill_rating = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)], blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        AlumniProfile, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.professional_skill)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Professional Skills'


class AlumniLanguageSkill(models.Model):
    language_skill = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    language_skill_rating = models.IntegerField(null=True,
                                                validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        AlumniProfile, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.language_skill)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Language Skills'


class AlumniComputerSkill(models.Model):
    computer_skill = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    computer_skill_rating = models.IntegerField(null=True,
                                                validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        AlumniProfile, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.computer_skill)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Computer Skills'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['user', 'computer_skill'], name='unique_user_computer_skill'),
        ]


class AlumniTraining(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AlumniProfile, null=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    training_title = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    training_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    trainer = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    training_location = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.training_title)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Trainings'


class AlumniProfessionalCertification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AlumniProfile, null=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    professional_certificate_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    certification_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    organization_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    organization_location = models.CharField(
        max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)
    certificate_attachment = models.FileField(
        upload_to='certificates/', null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.professional_certificate_title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Certifications'


class OthersActivities(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AlumniProfile, null=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activities_hobbies = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.activities_hobbies

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Activities/Hobbies'


class AlumniPublication(models.Model):
    pubication_title = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    pubication_journal = models.CharField(
        max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    published_on = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    publication_link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AlumniProfile, null=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pubication_title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Publications'


class AlumniTestimonial(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AlumniProfile, null=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    commented_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Testimonials'


class ServicesProvidedByAlumni(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AlumniProfile, null=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='services/', blank=True, null=True)
    service_short_description = models.CharField(
        max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.service)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Services Provided by Alumni'


class AlumniProfileSettings(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AlumniProfile, null=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    place_of_birth_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    phone_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    email_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    facebook_url_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    linkedin_url_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    instagram_url_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    twitter_url_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    skype_id_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    zoom_id_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    social_media_url_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    profile_pic_of_birth_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    present_address_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    permanent_address_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    website_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    work_experience_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    professional_skill_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    language_skill_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    computer_skill_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    testimonials_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    achievements_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    trainings_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    certifications_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    services_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    personal_album_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    publications_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    cv_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    blood_group_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    profile_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    cv_downloadable_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    cv_printable_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    posts_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    comments_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    personal_info_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    contact_info_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    hobbies_other_activities_visible_to_public = models.BooleanField(
        default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.profile_visible_to_public)
```

Code for views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def alumni_cv(request, pk):
alumniprofile = AlumniProfile.objects.filter(pk=pk)
education = AlumniEducation.objects.filter(user=pk).order_by('-exam_year')
jobexperience = AlumniJobExperience.objects.filter(
user=pk).order_by('-date_of_join')
alumniprofessionalskills = AlumniProfessionalSkill.objects.filter(user=pk)
alumnilanguageskills = AlumniLanguageSkill.objects.filter(user=pk)
alumnicomputerskills = AlumniComputerSkill.objects.filter(user=pk)
alumnitrainings = AlumniTraining.objects.filter(
user=pk).order_by('-training_date')
alumniprofessionalcertifications = AlumniProfessionalCertification.objects.filter(
user=pk)
alumniothersactivities = OthersActivities.objects.filter(user=pk)
alumnipublications = AlumniPublication.objects.filter(user=pk)
alumnitestimonials = AlumniTestimonial.objects.filter(user=pk)
alumniservices = ServicesProvidedByAlumni.objects.filter(user=pk)
alumniprofilesettings = AlumniProfileSettings.objects.filter(user=pk)
context = {'education': education, 'jobexperience': jobexperience, 'alumniprofile': alumniprofile,
'alumniprofessionalskills': alumniprofessionalskills, 'alumnilanguageskills': alumnilanguageskills,
'alumnicomputerskills': alumnicomputerskills, 'alumnitrainings': alumnitrainings,
'alumniprofessionalcertifications': alumniprofessionalcertifications,
'alumniothersactivities': alumniothersactivities, 'alumnipublications': alumnipublications,
'alumnitestimonials': alumnitestimonials, 'alumniservices': alumniservices,
'alumniprofilesettings': alumniprofilesettings}
return render(request, 'alumni_cv.html/', context)
```

urls.py code:

```
path('alumni_profile/<str:pk>/', alumni_profile, name='alumni_profile'),
url(r'^my_profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', my_profile, name='my_profile'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/my_cv/$', my_cv, name='my_cv'),
# url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/alumni_cv/$', alumni_cv, name='alumni_cv'),
path('<str:pk>/alumni_cv/', alumni_cv, name='alumni_cv'),
```

Indenting is ok in my file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `path('<int:pk>/alumni_cv/', alumni_cv, name='alumni_cv'),` (the type of pk is changed). If that didn't help please see [django url dispatcher.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `{% url 'alumni_cv' alumniprofile.id %}`